# Mouseover event not firing correctly

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am trying to display a tool-tip alert from a mouse over event on a button. however, what is happening is that the alert will only fire when I hover the mouse for the second time over the button. In other words I have to hover, leave then re-enter for the event to fire.

I would be grateful if someone could check my code to point out my mistake. Many thanks.

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bmfhj52k/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseover', '#srcsubmit', function() {
      if ($("#srcsubmit").prop('disabled') == true) {
        $("#srcsubmit").css('cursor', 'help');
        $('#srcsubmit').tipso({
          position: 'right',
          titleContent: 'Search Button Disabled',
          content: 'This field cannot be modified',
          background: '#889eb0',
          titleBackground: '#63a9e4',
          color: 'white',
          width: 275,
          size: 'default'
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

html

```
<input type="text" class="srcBox" id="srcBox" name="srcBox" />
  <input type="button" class="srcsubmit btn-primary" id="srcsubmit" Value="Search" />
 <div class="srchBoxError"></div>
 <br />
 <br />
<input type="text" class="srcBoxRslt" id="srcBoxRslt" name="srcBoxRslt" />
 <input type="button" class="srcRslt btn-primary" id="srcRslt" Value="Return" />
  <div class="dstrBoxError"></div>
```

Comment: please share HTML also and replicate your problem in a code snippet?

Comment: @AravindS I have added the relevant html code. Thanks

Comment: `mouseover` or mouse events will not work on disabled elements.

Comment: @JohnR Do you mean do not work period? because it does work correctly after second mouseover. thanks

Comment: Please show your problem here https://jsfiddle.net/g1nj8wbo/4/

Comment: @JohnR I cannot update the fiddle with the updated scripts to make it appear the same problem as what i am having. I need to add links for the tipso plugin. This works ok but when  i update it dosen't save the changes. thanks

Comment: @JohnR Check my post for updated fiddle. Thaks

Comment: You said `alert will only fire when I hover the mouse for the second time over the button`. But in that fiddle it is not firing.

Comment: Because basically `mouse` events will not fire for disabled elements.

Comment: What makes the button to disable? Is it disabled onload or programmatically? *(because I may have an idea for a walk around)*

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it is disabled programmatically like so: `$("#srcsubmit").prop("disabled", true)` Thanks

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I added the disabled property for the fiddle.

Comment: @JohnR well it is working that way in fiddle for me. Move mouse over the button then leave and on the next mouseover it will fire.

Comment: It may depends on browsers... Here in Chrome, the event never fires.

Comment: @user1532468 I got your problem. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with `firefox` browser, you can use the mouse events even the elements are disabled. But it will not work with other browsers(specifically chrome).

**Solution for your issue:**

The problem is `tipso` plugin is defining on the first `mouseover` action only. And then for next `mouseover` only it is starts working. So you need to place the `tipso` code definition in the `ready` function itself.

Just place the `tipso` code definition outside the `mouseover` event like below code snippets.

**Code snippets:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#srcsubmit').tipso({
    position: 'right',
    titleContent: 'Search Button Disabled',
    content: 'This field cannot be modified',
    background: '#889eb0',
    titleBackground: '#63a9e4',
    color: 'white',
    width: 275,
    size: 'default'
  });
  $(document).on('mouseover', '#srcsubmit', function() {
    if ($("#srcsubmit").prop('disabled') == true) {
      $("#srcsubmit").css('cursor', 'help');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bmfhj52k/5/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much John. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that mouse event do not occur on disabled elements is the key issue.

So here is a *tweaky walk-around*.
You will use an absolutely positionned div (semi-transparent red in this demo... For you to see it) to place right over the disabled button. On that div, you will instantiate Tipso... Not on the button.

Now you only will have to show/hide that div while enabling/disabling the button. It only serves as a "mouse event zone" for Tipso.

Sounds good?

```js
$(function() {
  
  // Get our 2 elements in variables to avoid useless lookups
  var srcsubmit = $("#srcsubmit");
  var srcsubmit_zone = $("#srcsubmit-zone");
  
  // Hide the "zone" if the button is NOT disabled
  if (!srcsubmit.prop('disabled')) {
    srcsubmit_zone.hide();
  }

  // Get the button dimentions and position
  var srcsubmitDimention = {
    height: srcsubmit.outerHeight(true),
    width: srcsubmit.outerWidth(true),
    top: srcsubmit.offset().top,
    left: srcsubmit.offset().left
  }
  
  // Place the "zone" div over the button
  srcsubmit_zone.css({
    "height":srcsubmitDimention.height,
    "width":srcsubmitDimention.width,
    "left": srcsubmitDimention.left,
    "top": srcsubmitDimention.top
  });
  
  // Instantiate Tipso normally
  srcsubmit_zone.tipso({
    position: 'right',
    titleContent: 'Search Button Disabled',
    content: 'This field cannot be modified',
    background: '#889eb0',
    titleBackground: '#63a9e4',
    color: 'white',
    width: 275,
    size: 'default'
  });
});
```

```css
#srcsubmit-zone{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);  /* Just for you to see it's over the button */
  position: absolute;
  cursor: help;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tipso/1.0.8/tipso.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tipso/1.0.8/tipso.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="srcBox" id="srcBox" name="srcBox" />
<input type="button" class="srcsubmit btn-primary" id="srcsubmit" Value="Search" disabled/>
<div id="srcsubmit-zone"></div>
<div class="srchBoxError"></div>
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" class="srcBoxRslt" id="srcBoxRslt" name="srcBoxRslt" />
<input type="button" class="srcRslt btn-primary" id="srcRslt" Value="Return" />
<div class="dstrBoxError"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Louys.